# Loading and caching array or PDF files using Parse to load into WebView - Swift

Tags: swift, pdf, caching, parse-platform, webview

I have data stored on parse which I am using to populate a UITableView as the master view and on clicking a row the detail is shown (PDF file in webview).  All of this data is currently stored on parse and using `object.cachepolicy = .NetworkElseCache`  The tableview will load without network from the cache. The PDF will only load if there is a network connection but will THEN cache requiring the user to first physically access each file before they become available offline.  Is there a way to cache all of the content within the class (strings and PDF Files) so it will download all of the content when the app is first opened, not with  each row selection.  This is how I am loading the web view

> ```
>             let url = NSURL (string: urlfile.url!);
>     let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
>     webview.loadRequest(requestObj);
> ```

Where the string is (https:// and so on) so it is pointing to an online source but only caches when it is clicked.  Hope this all makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you would like to download all of the PDFs associated with the tableview data right away, rather than waiting for the user to select an individual row which then attempts to access its respective PDF and fetches if necessary.

To achieve this, you could store the PDF data using PFFiles locally with the same cache policy and fetch them whenever the data is nil (such as on first use). Just associate the PFFile URL attributes to your PDF URLs and fetch them in the background as soon as your tableview is appears.

You will most likely only want to perform this if the user is on wifi because it could be a lot of data to download over the cell network.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just can't work this out!  Yes you are right I want to load the entire table of PDFs to the cache on opening the tableview ready to be accessed without the need for network.  I am storing them as PFFiles on the MainViewController 'self.pdfArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("PDFFile") as! PFFile)' but the only way I can get it to load in the pdf is to call the url thus pointing to an https:// url requiring a connection... (I should add the ' var urlfile = PFFile()' above the code in the initial question.

Comment: PFFiles automatically cache their data for you. The PDF files should be associated to some class you've created on Parse. When your query containing those class objects for the table data is complete, use those objects to call getDataInBackground on each object's respective PFFile (the PDF)

Comment: Perfect.  it didn't make any sense for the PFFile purely to contain a url and querying it on the first page was downloading ALL of the contents, I just wasn't getting the data and putting it into the webview.  '        let data = urlfile.getData()
        webview.loadData(data, MIMEType:"application/pdf", textEncodingName:nil, baseURL:nil)'    Done.  Thank you for your help